# Installing GnuCOBOL something missing

Tags: cygwin, cobol, gnucobol

Hello Im trying to install GnuCOBOL

in part of configuration I got that message

configure: error: no acceptable ld found in $PATH

if someone can help plz, thank u.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/help/

Comment: You'll need to use Cygwin setup.exe to install `make`, `gcc`, `gmp`, `libgmp-devel`, `ncurses`, `libncurses-devel`, `libdb`, `libdb-devel` possibly others in the development group.

Comment: I have no clue how the comment and answer got to "cygwin", but if this answer helped, then please mark it as answer. If you're outside of cygwin there's commonly a meta-package "build-essentials" which can be installed to add all important parts (having a compiler but not a linker _is_ quite seldom...),.

Answer (score 1):

Moving a comment to an answer, for completeness.

You'll need to use Cygwin setup.exe to install binutils, make, gcc, gmp, libgmp-devel, ncurses, libncurses-devel, libdb, libdb-devel, possibly others in the *development* package group.